# MongoDB 2dSphere indexing embedded document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, geospatial

```
var LocationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({'type': { type: String }, coordinates : []},{_id:false});


var EventsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title:String,
    status:String,
    location:[new mongoose.Schema({
        ll:[LocationSchema],
        type:String
    },{_id:false})] ,
});
```

Code to add a document:

```
function (req,res) {
   var event = new Events();
   var sLoc = new Location();
   var dLoc = new Location();

   event.title = req.body.title;
   event.startdate = req.body.startdate;

   sLoc.coordinates.push(parseFloat(req.body.slong));
   sLoc.coordinates.push(parseFloat(req.body.slat));
   sLoc.type= "Point";

   dLoc.coordinates.push(parseFloat(req.body.dlong));
   dLoc.coordinates.push(parseFloat(req.body.dlat));
   dLoc.type = "Point";

   event.location.push({ll:sLoc,type:"s"});
   event.location.push({ll:dLoc,type:"d"});

   event.save();
}
```

When I try to save the document, it give an error -- "Can't extract geo keys from object, malformed geometry?:{ 0: { type: [ -122.1251274, 37.4096933 ] } }"

I am making above query in mongoosejs with nodejs

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure that your problem is in the bit of code that you've shown here.  Are you sure that the objects "req" and "res" are storing information the way they are meant to be?  If I just replace "req.body.slong" etc. with a float like "83.9172", then this works for me.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I don't remember but I somehow fixed the problem by saving the data in a different way. Thanks again and I will debug more if I encounter similar problem.